# Get result depending on between dates using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an Entity Framework query to return a list of salaries and its clients as:

```
public async Task<List<Salary>> GetSalaryByClientIdAndProfileId(int profileId, int clientId)
{
    var profileClientSalary = this._db.Salaries.Where(pc => pc.ProfileId == profileId && pc.ClientId == clientId).OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate);
    return profileClientSalary.Include(pc => pc.Client).Where(p => p.ProfileId == profileId).ToList();
}
```

As you can see, I added Client Entity to the object, so my parent object has the property `startDate` and the Client entity has `ClientName`, `ContractStartingDate`, and `ContractEndDate`, I want to get on each parent the client name/s where parent `startDate` is between Client `ContractStartingDate` and `ContractEndDate`

So I have a foreach of the parent object as:

```
foreach(var salary in profileClientSalary)
{
    profile.Salaries.Add(new ProfileSalariesViewModel
    {
        StartDate = salary.StartDate,
        Customers = salary.Client.Name.Where(c => c.) 
        // Here I want to get client names where salary.startDate between Client.ContractStartingDate and Client.ContractEndDate
    });
}
```

Note: if the `Client.ContractEndDate` is null the client should be added to the list too

How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: Why do you have a `.Where` clause on the client name? Shouldn't it be on the client? Also, shouldn't it be `Clients` if it's a collection?

Comment: what I would do is `var filteredProfiles = profileClientSalary.Where(p => p.Salary >= xxxx && p.Salary <= yyyy);`

Comment: Yes, Clients is a collection @RufusL

Comment: Can you please add code for all related entites?

Comment: A usual naming standard is having collections a name ending with "s", so whoever reads it knows easily that there could be multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way could be using EF.Functions for the date comparison, but it might be a bit overkill.

If you want to make up a date from multiple properties:

```
var filteredSalaries = profileClientSalary.Where(salary => EF.Functions.DateFromParts(salary.year, salary.month, salary.day) >= contractStartDate &&
                                                           EF.Functions.DateFromParts(salary.year, salary.month, salary.day) <= contractendDate);
```

Or Just:

```
var filteredSalaries = profileClientSalary.Where(salary => salary.startDate >= contractstartDate &&
                                    salary.startDate <= contractendDate);
```

Just change <= to < if you don't want to include the exact start and end date.

And finally, if you just want the names.

```
var clientNames = filteredSalaries.select(salaries => salaries.ClientName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like this

```
    profile.Salaries.Add(new ProfileSalariesViewModel
    {
        StartDate = salary.StartDate,
        Customers = salary.Client.Where(c => c.ContractStartingDate > StartDate && c.ContractEndDate < StartDate).Select(c => c.Name); 
    });
```

The issue with your original code is that you're iterating over the name when you really need to be iterating over the clients and building a list of those first based on your filtering criteria.

Once you have that list of clients, you can select the customer names from that list with another linq query `Select(c => c.Name);`

Comment: I tried but it throws an error:                      `Client' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Client' could be found `

Comment: One of two things could be happening. Either Client isn't a collection or you're missing the linq reference. If you're just missing the reference then you need to import the Linq library. If you're using visual studio click on `Where` in your code, then hold CTRL+Period and it will bring up the option to import it. Or just at the top of your code write `using System.Linq`. It's hard to give you an exact answer without knowing all of the data structures